# MySQL Random rows in neighbourhood

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, random

I have this table (*PERSONS*) with 25M rows:

```
ID int(10) PK
points int(6) INDEX
some other columns
```

I want to show the user 4 random rows which are somewhat close to each other in points. I found this query after some searching and tuning to generate random rows which is impressive fast:

```
SELECT person_id, points
FROM persons AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT (RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(person_id)
                        FROM persons)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.person_id>= r2.id and points > 0
 ORDER BY r1.person_id ASC
 LIMIT 4
```

So I query this in the PHP. Which gives me great and fast results (below 0.05 seconds when warmed up). But these rows are really just random (with at least 1 point since the `points > 0`). I would like to show some rows which are a little bit close, doesn't have to be every time, but let's say I do this query with limit 50 and than select a random row in PHP and the 3 closest rows (based on points) next to it. I would think you would need to sort the result, pick a random row and show the rows after/before it. But i have no idea how I can make this, since I am quite new to PHP.

Anyone suggestions, all feedback is welcome :)

Comment: the query goes from 0.05 sec to 2.6213 sec

Comment: Then it's matter of optimizing your table, do you have index on points?

Comment: Yes it has an index on it

Comment: Sub-Selects are allways problematic. In most cases the optimizer will have to run your sub-select for each row in the main-select ... which is very bad. I would do two separate queries. Should be MUCH faster.
On another note, you can do a sub-select directly as a column (if it only returns one column) and not do a join. This should also improve performance if you still want to do it as a sub-select.

Comment: To-Be what you mean, could you please explain?

Comment: I'll do it as a possible answer, have better syntax highlighting there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build an index on your `points` column (if it does not already exist), then perform your randomisation logic on that:

```sql
ALTER TABLE persons ADD INDEX (points);

SELECT   person_id, points
FROM     persons JOIN (
           SELECT RAND() * MAX(points) AS pivot
           FROM   persons
           WHERE  points > 0
         ) t ON t.pivot <= points
ORDER BY points
LIMIT    4
```

Note that this approach will select the pivot using a uniform probability distribution over the range of `points` values; if `points` are very non-uniform, you can end up pivoting on some values a lot more often than others (thereby resulting in seemingly "non-random" outcomes).

To resolve that, you can select a random record by a more uniformly distributed column (maybe `person_id`?) and then use the `points` value of that random record as the pivot; that is, substitute the following for the subquery in the above statement:

```sql
           SELECT   points AS pivot
           FROM     persons JOIN (

                      SELECT FLOOR(
                               MIN(person_id)
                             + RAND() * (MAX(person_id)-MIN(person_id))
                             ) AS random
                      FROM   persons
                      WHERE  points > 0

                    ) r ON r.random <= person_id
           WHERE    points > 0
           ORDER BY person_id
           LIMIT    1
```

Comment: You should definetly check EXPLAIN there to see that it only does the sub-query once and not for each row. Should work though. ;)

Comment: @eggyal, after testing it I found out that only the lower points rows are selected, when i have 300 rows all between 1 and 100 points I only get randoms (tried over 60 times) with points between 1 and 20.. How is this possible?

Comment: @eggyal, thanks a lot man. One last question, you seem to know a lot more than me about SQL :) lets say i have 300 persons in the table, the points are between 1-100. Let's say 5 persons have 23 points as example, this query will always select the first 4, would it be possible to give them all an even chance to show up in de random function? Since I want to give every person a same % of chance to be shown.

Comment: @eggyal I tried to merge those 2 into 1 sql query but I still get the first results of a certain points :/ what did i do wrong? Wish I was an expert like you.

Comment: @KevinVermaat: Can you reproduct on http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84968/1

Comment: @KevinVermaat: let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30354/discussion-between-eggyal-and-kevin-vermaat).

Comment: @KevinVermaat: check out my latest messages in chat; slightly modified query with an index on `(points, person_id)` (replacing both the indexes on `points` alone and that on `(person_id, points)`) seems to perform pretty well.  Interested to hear your results?

Comment: found it, testing now

Answer (score 0):

Removing a subquery from it will drasticly improve the performance and caching so you could for example get list your IDs, put it in a file and then random from it (for example by reading random lines from file). This will improve it by a whole lot, as you can see if you will run EXPLAIN on this query and compare it by changing the query to load just data for the 4 (still random) ids.

Comment: Nope this is not true, i did read a lot about it and it is quite complicated, but for example the answer of ToBe takes over 3 seconds to execute, while the answer of @eggyal takes 0.006 seconds

Comment: @KevinVermaat what is not true? That this approach will not optimize? Of course that it will! Reading random 4 lines from a file is much faster than taking 4 random IDs from database :). Granted that it's not "sql-way" but it works.

Comment: Hey sorry i was reading too fast, you are right, but unfortunately I need the DB solution.

Comment: I think many online apps can't use a file for reading or writing data, for security reasons. Also databases have many advantages like build in integrity like FK's and transactional writing to it.

Comment: @KevinVermaat that is a VERY false statement. Writing/reading is in no way a breach of security and without reading files, you couldn't even import them. Even the (now dead, thank gods) safe_mode didn't prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing two separate sql queries in PHP and not join/subquery them. In many cases the optimizer can not simplify your query and has to perform each one separatly. So, in your case. if you have 1000 persons the optimizer will do the following wueries at worst case:

- Get 1000 persons rows
- Do Sub Select for each person which get's 1000 persons rows
- Join 1000 persons with joined rows resulting in 1.000.000 rows
- Filter all of them

In short:
1001 queries with 1.000.000 rows

My advice?

Perform two queries and NO joins or sub-selects as both (especially in combination have dramatic performance drops in most cases)

```sql
SELECT person_id, points 
FROM persons 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Now use the found points for your second query

```sql
SELECT person_id, points, ABS(points - <POINTS FROM ABOVE>) AS distance 
FROM persons 
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Your first query takes over 3.0974 sec to execute. I did read a lot about random rows for tables this big, it's smart to avoid order by RAND() ;)

Comment: Alternative to that? Btw, the solution above still uses RAND() but as a column and not within a where condition. This could be done here too, the point of this answer is to split geting random and getting other rows into two queries. ;)

Comment: Ok, I analyzed the above method of randomizing @eggyal. It really seems to work nicely, and combined with the added math for getting 4 items within range, it should be the way to go.
Public opinnions still seems to be that PHP can be fater in many cases, maybe not this one...